# extract set of lines from file based on pattern match

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regular-language

I have a file that contains thousands of tuples(set of three lines) as follows:

```
# dev2
SAMETEXT %{URI} ^dev2-00.XXX.XXX.XXX
SAMETEXT %{URI}  ^/XXX/
DIFFTEXT ^/XXX/(.*) https://XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-dev2.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XXX/$1 [X,Y]
```

There are multiple sets of same kind with different data such as dev1, dev2, dev3. Now I want to get all lines in same manner as they are in the file except dev2. File have a random or mixed groups but all groups are tuple of same lines as mentioned above.

I tried to get it with the following pattern but it give all other tuples as well which lies inside this span.

```
Pattern dev2Pattern = Pattern.compile("dev2\\R.*dev2-00.*\\RRewriteRule.*dev2", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

However, my objective is NOT to get matched pattern in resulted file. Thankx in advance.

Comment: If you want to match all the lines after `# dev ` except when it is # dev 2 Try `^# dev(?!2\b)[0-9]+(?:\R(?!# dev[0-9]).*)*` See https://regex101.com/r/p2ikOn/1

Comment: did not work in java program.

Comment: In Java the backslashes should be double escaped. `String regex = "^# dev(?!2\\b)[0-9]+(?:\\R(?!# dev[0-9]).*)*";`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match all the lines after `# dev` except when it is `# dev 2` you could use a negative lookahead to assert what is right after dev is not 2.

Then match all lines that do not start with `# dev` followed by a digit.

```
^# dev(?!2\b)[0-9]+(?:\R(?!# dev[0-9]).*)*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `# dev(?!2\b)` Match `# dev` and assert what is directly on the right is not 2 and word boundary
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing grouop

  - `\R` Match unicode newline sequence
  - `(?!# dev[0-9])` Assert what is directly to the right is not `# dev` and a digit
  - `.*` If that is the case, match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p2ikOn/1) | [Java Demo](https://ideone.com/x5PXZ9)

In java

```
String regex = "^# dev(?!2\\b)[0-9]+(?:\\R(?!# dev[0-9]).*)*";
```